# NextAuth.js Error: [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] Unexpected token '<' "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Below is the error I am geting

[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON {error: {…}, url: '/api/auth/session', message: `Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

I have reviewed my configuration and it seems correct, wondering why I'm encountering this issue.

Here's my setup :

**Google Client ID and Secret**: I've set up the Google client ID and secret in my environment variables.
**NextAuth Configuration**: I'm using the GoogleProvider from NextAuth with the correct clientId and clientSecret.
**SessionProvider**: I have a SessionProvider wrapping my components to provide session data.

Despite double-checking everything, this error persists.

**Below is NextAuth Configuration:**

**api/auth/[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

**// AuthProvider.js**

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default AuthProvider;

**// RootLayout.js**
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { ThemeProvider } from "../context/ThemeContext";
import AuthProvider from "../app/components/AuthProvider/AuthProvider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Testing",
  description: "This is the description",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeProvider>
          <AuthProvider>
            <div className="container">
              {children}
            </div>
          </AuthProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I attempted to implement authentication in my Next.js app using NextAuth with the Google provider. I I configured the Google Client ID and Secret, set up the NextAuth configuration using the GoogleProvider, and wrapped my components in a SessionProvider for session management.`your text`

Answer (score 3):

I also had these errors and I was able to fix them with a few things
First, about this error: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSO

Unfortunately, I had placed Auth folder outside the API and then changed it to:

```
api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
```

Then I added the following values to .env or .env.local:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

NEXTAUTH_SECRET=mytestApp
```

,

And it was resolved

Comment: Yes thank you. This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Place code in
//api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        // GithubProvider({
        //     clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
        //     clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
        // }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    ],
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Hope it will work on nextjs V13.5+

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on a Ubuntu Nginx VPS. I solved it by adding

```
nextauth_internal_url= MY_VPS_IP
```

and adding the `.env` file on the folder of the app at the server. Also, you have to include `nextauth-secret` and `nextauth-url=http://example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `yourlocalhost/api/auth/session` is accessible. If it's not, I think my answer can help.

The Error means that the page is expecting a json but it's receiving html.

To fix, make sure your route is `api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

My specific mistake was adding `.ts` to `[...nextauth]`, making it `[...nextauth].ts/route.ts` instead of `[...nextauth]/route.ts`

P.S, my specific error was

> app-index.js:32 [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]
> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected token
> '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON  Object client :  true error :
> {message: `Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`,
> stack: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`, name: 'SyntaxError'} message :  "Unexpected token '<',
> "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" url :  "/api/auth/session"

Answer (score 0):

in my side 2 issues :

- the "route.ts" was not in the correct folder it should be in "app\api\auth[...nextauth]
- in the middleware.ts "api" was not authorized in "matcher"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I have just fixed that.

In next.config.js, I have a basePath config. Delete it and the issue has gone.

I guess that the NEXTAUTH_URL and basePath doesn't match together.

I just add basePath recently to config nginx subpath

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the issue was middleware was blocking the /api path. once I added the api inside the matcher. the issue was solved.